# MS excel : Freeze the current date value using a NON VBA approach

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet

VBA can turn over  Excel anyway you want .SO pl understand this question is NOT the duplicate of a similar question that asks how to get it done using VBA.

I would like to assign the current date to a cell and PRESERVE that value 
That means after opening the file a few days , on the value should NOT change How do I get this done using a NON VBA formula based approach
`a1=Date()` 
but the date value does not change.

***Thank you both***. You both rock.  But stack will not let you do > 1 
Both answers are practicable but given the  reqs, I had - I just wanted to
'dirty stick in' the date wherever I want without scratching around . 
The 1st answer is useful if you have a conditional logic 1 col
update should get a date in ,the other column. The 2nd one does the
*quick stick* of the date.

Comment: You can't do this with a formula.  You would have to convert the date to a value to make sure it doesn't change.  If the cell still contains a formula, it will update.  I suppose you could turn calculation to manual, but as soon as you need to calculate anything, the date will update anyway.

Comment: @Tgeravatar You can do with iterative calculation like in my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the problem.  If you want a static date in  a cell, just click on the cell and enter something like:

```
2/11/2016
```

The date will not change unless you change it.

If you are not certain of the current date, then click on the cell and touch:

<kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>  + <kbd>**;**</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Like said many times at this side:

Goto options -> formulas -> enable iterative calculation
Then in A1:

```
=IF(A2="","",IF(A1="",NOW(),A1))
```

If you put anything in A2 then A1 will become the actual date/time and stay with this value as long as A2 is not empty... it will not change in later calculations ;)

You can try this with the actual formula (showing also time including seconds) it will not change. If you empty out A2 and reinsert something, it will jump to the new time and then stay with that value as long as you want (even close/open will not change that)